# Success page after redirect from Payment gateway

Tags: onepage-checkout

I have issues with displaying the success page.Please see process flow below:

After PlaceOrder action, the customer is redirected to payment gateway and after transaction is completed, I redirected to a controller on magento site. This gives me opportunity to get th transaction status and save the details in a custom table.

My issue is after saving, and redirect to check_oneoage_success.xml, it gives me error "1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException): Id required", kindly assist.

Answer (score 1):

If you are overriding Onepage success controller and implementing your custom logic, in this case you will not get LastOrderId in 'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action' event which is dispatched in the success action controller.

Thats why it is throwing 'Id required' input exceptions.

Avoid Overridding Onepage controller action

```
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success" type="Arman\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success" />
```

Instead of integrating your specific peice of code in success controller, try to use observer checkout_onepage_controller_success_action which is being dispatched in success action controller and implement your logic in observer.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {        
             $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
                 //enter code here
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    }
```

Hope, It will solve your problem, as I was getting the same error and it is solved for me with this approach

[image: Screenshot for the Error]